# RubyMotion & SpriteSheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, rubymotion

I have a sprite sheet, and would like to use it using UIImage in Rubymotion.

Anybody can provide a sample code on how to display an image from the spritesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a recent Rubymotion gem for that called 'motion-sprites', see http://jjuliano.github.com/motion-sprites/